# Why can't my VirtualBox CentOS communicate with Network/Internet

Tags: linux, centos, networking, virtualbox

I've set up CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-minimal.iso in VirtualBox 6.0.22.

When creating the VM I chose:
Network-->Adapter 1-->Attached to: Bridged Adapter

It's my understanding that with this setting I should be able to ping other devices on the network and, if a proxy is provided, the internet in general.

However, I cannot.  I can't download anything (like `dnf copr enable...` gives errors like `Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https:...`)

When I run `route -n` I get

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination  Gateway  Genmask    Flags  Metric  Ref     Use  Iface
```

No gateway ip is shown.  When I try `sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1` I get

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

UPDATE: Someone pointed out that this gateway ip is from another network.  How do I find out the ip of the gateway?

If I run `ip addr` I get:
[image]

If I run `ping www.google.com` I get:

```
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known
```

A person had this exact behavior from his raspberry pi here: [IP Routing Table is Empty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100821/ip-routing-table-is-empty?newreg=4bc01ba53046442bb3c25d9f8e74262e).  Their fix was to physically connect it to their network with an Ethernet cable, which established the gateway.  I found someone with a similar case here: [why-can-not-connect-internet-from-centos-on-virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823073/why-can-not-connect-internet-from-centos-on-virtualbox)  Their answer was to tick "Cable Connected" under Settings-->Network.  My problem is that option is already ticked and yet I have no connection.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you cut and paste the text of the `ip addr`? All I see now is a partial picture of a screenshot where most of the important information is missing.

Comment: @LjmDullaart, thank you for commenting.  That screenshot shows 100% of the output (beginning with `1:  Io: <LOOPBACK...` and ending with `...:ff :ff :ff`.  there's no more output before or after that.  The next line is just a new prompt line.

Comment: I used screenshot bc I can't figure out yet how to copy from the virtualbox terminal.

Comment: In VirtualBox, choose the machine, general, advanced and enable shared clipboard.

Comment: If you look in VirtualBox under Tools, network, choose your network (probably NAT network) and choose "edit". Is the DHCP server enabled here? Jot down your CIDR for this network. If you assign an IP manually, make sure it is on this subnet.